# Determine if Android APK leverages Marmalade SDK

Tags: android, sdk, apk, marmalade

Is there a way to determine if an Android App APK was created leveraging Marmalade (C++ SDK, Juice, Quick, or Web)? Will the android manifest have any activities or values that might indicate it leverages Marmalade? Will any files exist that give an indication?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple if you have the apk file with you.

Rename the app's extension to `zip` and open it in winrar or winzip. Loop up in the `assets` folder. If the app's name is `ExampleApp` and if it's made with marmalade, there'd be `ExampleApp.s3e` file in the assets folder. If it's not made from maramalade, it won't be there.

So basically you'll just have to find if any s3e file is present in assets or not.

Comment: disclaimer: I checked it with C++ SDK only, although it should work with Web and Quick too. I have no idea about Juice, since I don't have it's license

Comment: What if it has foo.s3e? Is .s3e a Marmalade-only thing?

Comment: Marmalade has a list of APIs written in both C and C++. The C APIs start from s3e and the C++ ones start from Iw (IwGx). The extensions also uses s3e prefix. That's all I know about S3E. 
I am not sure, but I suppose that's Marmalade only thing. You can find more info here - http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Working+with+S3E+APIs